# How do I instantiate a DOMRect?

Tags: haxe

I am trying to check whether two rects overlap, one of which comes from getBoundingClientRect, the other I am trying to construct from a mouse position.

I've already discovered that ClientRect is deprecated. Haxe now has a class called DOMRect, but when I try to instantiate it, I get a "cannot be called" warning. I am using haxe 3.2

In the haxe [source](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/js/html/DOMRect.hx) it seems that the constructor for this class returns void, which doesn't make a lot of sense. The name is also pretty dumb, because I might be making rects which have no relation to the DOM.

Is it not possible to instantiate this thing? If so, what is the point of it?

Do I have to make an anonymous 'rect' or use a map of floats instead?

Comment: Is that a compiler or runtime error you're getting? The [MDN page on DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect/DOMRect) states that it's an experimental API only supported in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks! It's a compiler error.

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error on [try.haxe.org](http://try.haxe.org/#c1851): `Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMRect is not defined` (in Chrome anyway, I suspect it would work in Firefox)

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue is?

Comment: I never figured it out.
I ended up rolling my own rect class with the methods I needed to deal with intersections.

Comment: Following up here, the live haxe example posted by @Gama11 now seems to work, and the MDN page indicates that DOMRect is now fully supported by all modern browsers. IE is (naturally) not one of them. If there was an issue, I suppose it was haxe and browser catchup. I no longer need a solution, and my question is no longer valid. Not sure if it's better to close the Q, or leave it open for old time's sake.